# Difference between "removable drive hot-plugged" and "removable media inserted"?

Tags: mount, xubuntu, usb-drive, hotplug

On Xubuntu's "Removable Drives and Media" settings, I see two items that can each be checked on/off that seem very similar. Can someone explain what the difference is?

Under the "Storage" tab are

[ ] Mount removable drives when hot-plugged

[ ] Mount removable media when inserted

The screenshot below shows them (see the checked ones):

[image]

(And, as an aside: Why is there only "Browse removable media when inserted", but no "Browse removable drives when inserted"?)

Answer (score 1):

"Removable drives" probably refers to something like SATA drives that can be hot-plugged, like on a server, maybe eSATA as well.

"Removable media" probably means more along the lines of USB devices.

There is probably a difference between mounting a USB device and mounting a SATA device. USB drives are generally mounted automatically (optionally in this case), but other hard drives are not.